# Trigger Update Before Or After Update On Same Table

Tags: mysql, datetime, triggers, timestamp

I have this table:

[Table: product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4k7d.png)

By using PHPMYADMIN, I am thinking of setting a trigger so that whenever I make changes to the price on any item, it will trigger to record the time on the price_change_time for that particular item.

My trigger is like this:

```html
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_time BEFORE UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE product SET price_change_time = NOW() WHERE NEW.price <> OLD.price;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Sadly this won't work and I get:

```html
MySQL said:Documentation

#1442 - Can't update table 'product' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I read some of the previous asked questions and answers which is somehow related, but still not able to suit it for my case.

Anyone willing to help? My question is:

```
1) Is there any way to achieve what I want by just using PHPMYADMIN?
2) If Not then what is the proper way?
```

Comment: A trigger in MySQL cannot act on the table which caused it to fire, so you will need to think of another way.  FYI that you have this need may imply that your design has a problem.

Comment: I think of EXCEL...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column in a MySQL table [something like this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

```
CREATE TABLE product (
...
price_change_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
...
);
```

This creates a "magic" column in your table that gets updated to the current time whenever its row is first INSERTed or UPDATEd.

Recent versions of MySQL, but not older ones, also allow this for `DATETIME` columns.

You can use `DATE(price_change_time)` to retrieve just the date part of a timestamp.

Comment: Triggers are a big pain in the neck compared to this, partly because they don't work, and partly because, well, they're a big pain in the neck.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It is better than nothing, thanks. Anyway, is it possible to put some constraint or condition so that it only renew timestamp if the price was being updated? If I change other data like item or location, I don't want renew timestamp.

Comment: Also, the timestamp is in this format: 2018-04-02 19:52:50, is there any way I can make it just date, like 2018-04-02, because exact time is not important for me.